# Flink uses more memory than taskmanager.memory.process.size in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-flink

In Flink 1.10.0, we try to use `taskmanager.memory.process.size` to limit the resource used by taskmanager to ensure they are not killed by Kubernetes. However, we still get lots of taskmanager `OOMKilled` with the following setup.

Any suggestion about how to setup Kubernetes and Flink properly so that we don't have `OOMKilled`?

- The Kubernetes setup is the same as described in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html.
- The following is resource configuration for taskmanager deployment in Kubernetes:

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 4096Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 4096Mi
```

- The following are all memory related configurations in `flink-conf.yaml` in 1.10.0:

```
jobmanager.heap.size: 820m
taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 128m
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 4096m
```

- We use RocksDB and we don't set `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed` in `flink-conf.yaml`.
- Not sure how to check if we have `any substantial off-heap memory allocations in your application code or its dependencies`. Any tool suggested to do so?

  The following is our dependencies FYI.

```
val flinkVersion = "1.10.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.squareup.okhttp3" % "okhttp" % "4.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-metrics-dropwizard" % flinkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-statebackend-rocksdb" % flinkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.6.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.log4s" %% "log4s" % "1.8.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.rogach" %% "scallop" % "3.3.1"
```

- The configuration we used in Flink 1.9.1 are the following. It does not have `OOMKilled`.

  - Kubernetes

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 1200m
    memory: 2G
  limits:
    cpu: 1500m
    memory: 2G
```

- Flink 1.9.1

```
jobmanager.heap.size: 820m
taskmanager.heap.size: 1024m
```

Comment: Do you set any other memory related options 'taskmanager.memory.*' or any legacy memory options are set from 1.9 or earlier Flink versions?
If you use RocksDB state, is 'state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed' changed from default value?
Are there any substantial off-heap memory allocations in your application code or its dependencies?
Did it work with Flink 1.9?

Comment: [Memory setup in Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/memory/mem_setup.html)

Comment: [Memory calculation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mJaMkMPfDJJ-w6nMXALYmTc4XxiV30P5U7DzgwLkSoE)

Comment: @azagrebin Update information in post.

Comment: thanks for more details,
do I understand correctly that you are just trying to migrate the same job from 1.9 and 1.10? Basically, there has been no change in the user code of the job that worked with 1.9 and stopped working after migrating to 1.10 because of OOMKilled,
and it is a streaming job (DataStream API) as you use RocksDB state backend, right?

Comment: could you [create a JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK) and attach logs of killed TMs to it?

Comment: @azagrebin The JIRA ticket is submitted at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16267, and the log is attached. Thanks.